# iOS: How do I figure out the current orientation in viewWillAppear?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, orientation, screen-orientation, orientation-changes

I have a `UIWebView` that I would like to load different URLs depending on whether its portrait or landscape. How can I figure out what my current orientation is inside `viewWillAppear`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use UIApplication's [`statusBarOrientation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW10) property.  You may run into problems if you use the device orientation if it is [`UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp) or [`UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown).

**Example**

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation))
{
   // Do something when in landscape
}
else
{
   // Do something when in portrait
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
UIDeviceOrientation getCurrentOrientation() {
  UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
  [device beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
  UIDeviceOrientation currentOrientation = device.orientation;
  [device endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

  return currentOrientation;
}
```

It's up to you to convert the `UIDeviceOrientation` to `UIInterfaceOrientation`.

Answer (score 2):

When the app loads, it does not know its current orientation-

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) {
    NSLog(@"portrait");// only works after a rotation, not on loading app
}
```

Once you rotate the device, you get correct orientation, but when the app is loaded, without changing the orientation, it seems that using `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]` doesn't know the current orientation.

So you need to do 2 things -

1. Try setting the application's accepted device orientations in the plist file
2. In your UIViewControllers, you will need to override the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)` method to return YES when the app should `rotate:`

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question -- my orientations change fine (I have defined shouldAutorotate already), but I want to know which variable I can check to see which orientation I'm currently at.

Comment: check my updated answer. you need to implement - `UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];`

Comment: @Srikar I used `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]` for this purpose once and ended up having a bug in my code when the orientation was `UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp` or `UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown`.  That's when I switched to using `[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation`, which is of type `UIInterfaceOrientation` instead of `UIDeviceOrientation`.  Note that you don't have to show the statusbar for this code to work.  I think before making the change I was even using the macro `UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation)` when I ran into the face up / face down bug.

Answer (score 1):

If the is sequencing of relevant calls mean that you can't rely on `interfaceOrientation` having the correct value at `viewWillAppear` then — assuming the parent view controller rotates — the safest thing is probably `self.parentViewController.interfaceOrientation`. Failing that you could try making a first assumption from `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]`, which may not always be 100% on the money (e.g. if the device is lying flat on a table when your app is launched) but is likely to give you a better guess than always assuming portrait.